# What are the differences between "controlled natural language" and "toy grammar"?

Tags: terminology

I am working on NLP and also Linguistics field. I created my own toy grammar, but while browsing the literature, I came across the concept of controlled natural language. Are these two the same or different concepts?

Comment: This is a terminology question that I think would be better asked at [conlang.se].

Comment: @curiousdannii controlled natural language has nothing to do with conlangs. They are used in fields where mission-critical communication is important.

Comment: @prash If it's controlled it's a conlang IMO. I like [elemtilas's explanation](https://conlang.stackexchange.com/a/857/113): "Wikipedia lists it as a controlled natural language, which simply means that it is a natural language whose natural form and evolution have been suspended and its new form and evolution have been created by someone." There's clearly lots of overlap between these CNLs and auxiliary languages, and to the extent that removing ambiguity is a goal, also with logical languages.

Comment: @curiousdannii elemtilas explained his opinion, and I don't see a good enough reason to agree with it. Plenty of ordinary English sentences are perfectly valid sentences in many of the CNLs. All the tools and techniques of linguistics (and computational linguistics) meant for a specific general-use language are available for use as-is with a controlled version of that language. It is helpful to think of CNLs as an extreme form of a style guide.

Comment: @prash You don't have to agree. I was just explaining why I voted to close. But I'd hope that you'd agree that these controlled languages are not fully "natural". They're strict subsets and their potential speech/writing communities can't just bring in more from the source language without erasing the point of what they were created for.

Comment: @curiousdannii Any restriction creates a subset of the general language. Swear words are not allowed on BBC News broadcasts. Their language is not "fully natural" in many other ways. Creating a subset does not make a natural language a constructed language.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/105878/discussion-between-curiousdannii-and-prash).

Comment: @prash Toy grammars are definitely conlangs, but whatever.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Controlled natural languages](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Controlled_natural_language) are usually designed for some real life purpose, e.g., robust and safe communication of important facts in technology and commerce. They are also often designed to be easy to translate for MT (often the now old fashioned rule based MT systems). Controlled Natural Languages have only features coming from their Natural Language parent, but those features are a subset of the features of the parent language. A Controlled Natural Language should be immediately intelligible to speakers of the parent language although they may notice some unnaturalness (e.g., lack of idiomaticity or strange idioms) in the controlled language.

On the other hand, Toy Grammars or *Miniature Artificial Languages* are designed for psycholinguistic experiments. They often have features that do not occur in a natural language.